# how to change cell values to list format in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looks like as below

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | he, loves, me |
| B | she, hates, me |

and hoping to change it as below (converting to a list format)

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | [he, loves me] |
| B | [she, hates, me] |

I've tried

df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].values.tolist(),

but it changes the whole cell value to list, not by per row.. I would appreciate if someone can help on it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html).

```
df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].str.split(",")
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)
  Column A            Column B
0        A   [he,  loves,  me]
1        B  [she,  hates,  me]
```